# How do I write sequence of commands that prints the real users,their UID and default shell?

Tags: command-line, uid

Uptil I succeeded with users and UID with that code

```
sudo cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | egrep ':[0-9]{4}$'
```

How do I complete the code like this `bob:1000:/usr/bin/bash`?

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` to read (or `cut`) the `/etc/passwd` file

Comment: I would recommend against parsing the passwd file with sudo to minimize oops.

Comment: Now when two have said it, it has to be true...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read about [passwd file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd), you'll get to know that usually, 7th field contain shells. So, you need to specify that field in `cut` and remove `$` from `grep` (since `$` means line ending). Also, if you need the users whose UID has 4 characters, you can simply use another `:`.

```
cut -d: -f1,3,7 /etc/passwd | egrep ':[0-9]{4}:'
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! itws works perfect for me.